# Test MySQL DB connection, when 2 ports in same server for different DB are opened, while connecting in-proper port is given

Tags: java, jdbc

#### Use Case: Test the RDBMS connection using Java JDBC.

Scenario: In server '`A`' 2 ports are opened, say

- `3306` for MySQL DB
- `27017` for Mongo DB

.

To test the connection, when the MySQL details are given properly except port as '`27017`', the connection is not happening and it is going to **infinite loop** kind-of thing.

Tried below options:

```
?useSSL=false&connectTimeout=3
DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(3);
```

```
public boolean validateRdbmsConnection(String driverClassName, String url, 

String userName, String userPswrd) {
    if (StringUtils.isNoneBlank(driverClassName, url, userName, userPswrd)) {
        try {
            Class.forName(driverClassName);
            try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, 

userName, userPswrd)) {
                if (conn != null) {
                    DatabaseMetaData dm = conn.getMetaData();
                    System.out.printf("\nDatabase Metadata 
                    information:\n\tDriver name: %s\n\tDriver version: %s\n\tProduct name: 
                    %s\n\tProduct version: %s", dm.getDriverName(), dm.getDriverVersion(), 
                     dm.getDatabaseProductName(), dm.getDatabaseProductVersion());
                    System.out.println("Inside ConnectionServiceImpl.validateRdbmsConnection()... END");
                    return true;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            System.out.printf("Database Connection is NOT SUCCESSFUL. Exception occurred while trying to connect to the specified Database. Exception: %s", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

> Expected: Either 'Connection Timeout' or 'No DB' kind of exception.

## Actual:  Trying to get connection, going into infinite loop.

Comment: Your code doesn't have a loop, so how can it be going into an infinite loop?

Comment: I mean it is taking 'in-definite time' to get the connection. The connection is not happening or not throwing any exception...

Comment: The wording of your question (_"MySQL details are given properly except port as '27017'"_)  suggests that you are trying to connect to MongoDB using the MySQL Connector/J JDBC driver, and that is not going to work and could well result in a connection blocked reading from the socket depending on the specifics of either protocol.